# Constraining a UITableView to its superview's edges causes layout collision

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a simple `UITableView` that I've constrained to its superview's edges in `viewDidLoad`.

```
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
[tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;
tableView.rowHeight = 44;
[tableView registerClass:Cell.self forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

[self.view addSubview:tableView];

[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:0].active = YES;

[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:0].active = YES;

[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1 constant:0].active = YES;

[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1 constant:0].active = YES;

[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

However, I get 2 layout issues in the console when I build and run:

> 2017-08-24 12:08:21.676379-0400 objtest[62354:48633213]
>   [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>     Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one
>   you don't want.   Try this:       (1) look at each constraint and try to
>   figure out which you don't expect;        (2) find the code that added the
>   unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.    (Note: If you're
>   seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand,
>   refer to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "UITableView:0x7fcf0f017600   (active, names:
>   '|':UIView:0x7fcf0c604bf0 )>",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful.
>
> 2017-08-24 12:08:21.677146-0400
>   objtest[62354:48633213] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously
>   satisfy constraints.  Probably at least one of the constraints in the
>   following list is one you don't want.     Try this:       (1) look at each
>   constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;          (2) find
>   the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
>     (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you
>   don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful.

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you forgot:

```
tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```